# assert that invisible div exists

Tags: php, phpunit

I started in TDD and now I want to test that a invisible div exists. The div is the following:

```
<div style="display: none;" class="humane notice"><p>Datos actualizados con exito.</p></div>
```

and I tried with this code:

> ...
>
> ```
> $crawler = $client->click($crawler->selectLink('Eliminar')->link());
>
> // Miramos si redirige
> $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isRedirect('/admin/residente/'),"No redirige a Residente(index)(Eliminar)");
> $crawler = $client->followRedirect();
>
>
> /*
> * Miramos si existen las notificaciones
> */
> $this->assertEquals(1, $crawler->filter('.humane')->count() > 0,"(Notifikazioak) Notifikaziorik ez dago." );
> ```

The first assert fires a delete function witch works correctly and it returns to the index page where I can see my notification, this invisible code (humane.js) so the result of my test should be true, instead of false.

any help or clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have assertElementPresent() and assertVisible() methods in PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase class.

You can find full list of available asserts in comments of the source:
[PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php)